# HAL - UDISKS, human readable, convert bytes to gigabytes in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

**First Question**

I'm currently using HAL in a bash script to get the size of a specific device with following command.

```
HAL_SIZE=$(hal-get-property --udi $UDI --key storage.removable.media_size)
```

The result (e.g): *4110188544/*

But how can I convert this value to human readable format like GB:

```
4 110 188 544 bytes = 3.82791138 gigabytes
```

**Second Question**

```
    for UDI in $(hal-find-by-property --key storage.bus --string usb)
do
    HAL_TMP=`hal-get-property --udi $UDI --key storage.removable.media_available`
    if [ "$HAL_TMP" = "true" ]; then
        HAL_DEV=$(hal-get-property --udi $UDI --key block.device)
        HAL_SIZE=$(hal-get-property --udi $UDI --key storage.removable.media_size)
        HAL_TYPE=$(hal-get-property --udi $UDI --key storage.drive_type)
```

Does anybody have some expirence with *udisks*, because HAL won't be longer supported on the most linux distribution, so I am thinking of to use *udisks*

How do I have to adapt the above mentioned commands but use *udisks* instead of *hal*

Thanks!

Comment: i think q2 is more 'serverfault' than 'stackoverflow'. but maybe i think this because i can only answer q1!

Comment: I posted it on serverfault too ;)

Answer (score 1):

an answer to q1:

```
>bytes="4110188544/"; echo $(echo "scale=3;${bytes%/*}/1024/1024/1024"|bc)GB
3.827GB
```

this strips the trailing forward slash and uses 'bc' to convert bytes to GB. modify the scale integer for accuracy